# Force unescapeing of ajax query parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, urlencode, url-encoding

### What I am doing

I am building a query to a service. I query the service using ajax and get a response in JSON.

I am querying the Google map API service. [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

Here is a sample query:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

You can see the query parameters are `latlng`, and `sensor`.

There is a comma in the `latlng` query parameter.

### Let's look at some code

```
// Some vars
var googleEndpoint = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";

// Bind handler to form submission
$('#theQuery').submit(function() {
    var lat = $("#lat").val();
    var _long = $("#long").val();

    // Construct Query
    $.get(googleEndpoint, { sensor: true, latlong: lat + ',' + _long }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    return false;
});
```

If I run a query, my query looks like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&latlong=44%2C44
```

### My thoughts

You can see the comma is a `%2C`. I know this is due to `encodeURIComponent` being called on the parameters as jquery builds the query string, but I don't know how to flag that comma so that it won't be encoded. I have tried `unescape()`.

I know I am missing something here, **any help**?

Comment: The question is still interesting but as far as the Google service, the parameter is 'latlng' and NOT 'latlong' so the failure to make requests was due to this typo in my code above. If you pass a ',' OR a '%2C' both give valid responses. I will close this question.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using

[**encodeURI()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

It does not escape comma

Comment: This was helpful but see my comments on my original question on how I solved this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json",
        contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
        data:
            "path=36.578581,-118.291994&samples=3"
    });
```

My code works fine,hope to help you!

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?path=36.578581,-118.291994|36.23998,-116.83171&samples=3&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```